# Shorten string from NSDecimalNumber with K for thousands, and M for millions etc

Tags: iphone, ios, rounding, nsnumber, nsdecimalnumber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert int to shortened, formatted string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993806/convert-int-to-shortened-formatted-string)

I would like to convert the value of `NSDecimalNumber` to a string where:

5 to 6 digit numbers use K to represent thousands, and have 3 significant figures (e.g. 54,321 ---> 54.3K, 654,321 ---> 65.4K)

7 to 9 digit numbers use M to represent millions, and have 3 significant figures (e.g. 7,654,321 ----> 7.65M, 987,654,321 ---> 9.88M)

10 digit numbers and above use B to represent billions, and have 3 significant figures

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?  Thanks.

(Saw some similar questions, but not one for Objective-C/iOS.)

Comment: This answer should help. I'm using it and it works really well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993806/convert-int-to-shortened-formatted-string

Comment: I'm using `NSDecimalNumber` so I don't want to convert to `double`, but I'll try to use it as a guideline.

Answer (score 0):

[FormatterKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit) can format bits, bytes, megabytes, etc. See the TTTUnitOfInformationFormatter class.

Example:

Add TTTUnitOfInformationFormatter.h and TTTUnitOfInformationFormatter.m to your project. The following sample code will format the number 12345 as a count of bytes:

```
#import "TTTUnitOfInformationFormatter.h"

NSDecimalNumber *numberOfBytes = [NSDecimalNumber
                                  decimalNumberWithString:@"12345"];
TTTUnitOfInformationFormatter *formatter = [[TTTUnitOfInformationFormatter alloc]
                                            init];
// Set this to NO if you want to show bits instead of bytes.
formatter.displaysInTermsOfBytes = YES;
// Set this to YES if you want 1024 bytes in a KB instead of 1000 bytes.
formatter.usesIECBinaryPrefixesForCalculation = NO;
NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:numberOfBytes
                                           ofUnit:TTTByte];
NSLog(@"%@", formatted);
```

It will print:

```
12.35 KB
```

If you want "K" instead of "KB", "B" instead of "GB", etc. you could still use this class as a starting point.

Comment: Do you think you can post the relevant code from the project?  I'm pretty novice and it always takes me quite a while to figure these things out from the project source.  Thank you.

Comment: I added a working code sample.