# How can I extract the first 3 characters from an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How can I extract the first 3 characters from a NSString?

For example if I have a string "1234820" How can I extract the numbers 123 from the string and store the result in a new string with the format "1.23 Million" ?

I am counting the the number of characters in the string by using

```
 -(NSString *)returnFormattedString:(NSString *)stringToFormat{


    NSString *formatedString;
    NSUInteger characterCount = [stringToFormat length];
    if (characterCount > 6) {
      //???? How do I extract and add a decimal

        stringWithThreeCharactersAndDecimal = ????;

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:stringWithThreeCharactersAndDecimal];

    formatedString = [string stringByAppendingString:@"Million"];
    }
return formatedString;
}
```

Comment: Don't you want something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993806/convert-int-to-shortened-formatted-string) which is more versatile as it doesn't assume there are 7-digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

```
assume that is your String
 yourString = @"1234820";

// use substringToIndex for fetch First Three Character
yourString=[yourString substringToIndex:3];

// finally  convert string to as like 1.23
 NSString *finalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f  Million", [yourString floatValue]];
```

**Choice -2**

as per Droppys short and good answer is

```
 NSString *finalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f  Million",  [yourString floatValue] / 100.0f];
```

Comment: `[yourString floatValue] / 100.0f`.  What a mess.

Comment: @Droppy -- I agree your answer, we can do it in multiple ways,  just wait